# Best way to read from a table without having a mapped JPA entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Table `PRODUCTS` in the database that I need to read from. The table contains many columns but I only need 2 of them in my response. I don't want to create a full 1 to 1 `Entity` class for this table since it wouldn't make much sense. There are 2 ways that I have found on how to do it:

1. Create a projection class:

```
@Data
public class Product {
    private Long productId;
    private String productLabel;
}
```

To read from this I used this method:

```
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        var queryString = "SELECT product_id, product_label FROM PRODUCTS";

        Stream<Tuple> resultStream = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString, Tuple.class).getResultStream();

        return resultStream.map(tuple -> {
            Product product = new Product ();
            product.setProductId((Long) tuple.get("product_id"));
            product.setProductLabel((String) tuple.get("product_label"));

            return product;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

2. Second way I have seen suggested is to create my own JPA entity where I only have the 2 columns I need and use the usual `JPA` approach to read from it (so without using `nativeQuery`). This seems a bit problematic to me because I am creating an incomplete entity (meaning that I do not map all the existing columns to attributes).

I was curious as to which one of this 2 ways might be better to use.

*Note*: I will also mention I can't use any `JDBC` stuff like `JdbcTemplate` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both techniques have advantages and disadvantages, and which one is preferable depends on the unique needs of your application. A projection class is a smart choice when you need to extract a subset of columns from a database without loading the entire entity with all of its connections and relationships. This technique provides advantages such as lower memory utilisation, increased speed, simpler mapping, and more flexible querying. If you need greater query freedom and don't mind producing an incomplete object, developing a custom JPA entity is preferable.

Comment: Moreover, using a partial entity would allow you to update the mapped columns in the database and even add lines in the table if the partial provided data doesn't violate constraints.